# Ms SQL Server 2017 Possible Multiple select statements to create different columns in a view?

Tags: sql-server

My question is it possible in Ms SQL Server 2017 to write Multiple select statements to create different columns in a view ? if yes then

also please tell me how do I find a person's age in month from his date of birth to current date ?

Comment: It is possible to find a person's age using a single select statement. Why do you think one should use multiple select statements? How would you calculate a person's age manually? What have you tried so far to translate those instructions into a formula? Did you even try to ask your preferred Internet search engine?

Comment: Hello @WolfgangKais- I am very new to programming. I tried searching on Duckduckgo to which I got few answers like 
select convert(varchar(10),DOB,103) from Customer;
Now the reason I asked about multiple select statement is because I have 3 tables Customer, Transaction, prod_info. So my task is to Create a 360 view of different customer id . So one column required is age_in_months , other net sales which is a difference of two values, net quantity and like wise. Please suggest how to do it !

Comment: hello @WolfgangKais - also 
SELECT Convert(INT, DATEDIFF(DAY, '12/12/1990',(select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103))*(12.0/365.0)))

But my main motive is the column age_in_months should display the age in months. I run into lot of errors like character conversion.

Comment: `convert(varchar(10),DOB,103)`will not return an age but a just the DOB as a formatted string, `Convert(INT, DATEDIFF(DAY, '12/12/1990',(select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103))*(12.0/365.0)))` has some wrong bracketing and unneccessary sub-querying, it should read `SELECT CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(DAY, '12/12/1990',GETDATE())*12.0/365.0)`.

Answer (score 0):

How does this look? If you want more we need more explanation.

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20),DOB DATE)
INSERT INTO @TEMP(Name, DOB)
VALUES ('abcc','2000-01-01')
,('abcd','2004-01-01')
,('abce','2008-01-01')
,('abcf','2012-01-01')
,('abcg','2016-01-01')

select name, dob, DATEDIFF(mm,DOB,GETDATE()) 'Age_In_Months'
    ,(select DATEDIFF(yy,DOB,GETDATE()) from @TEMP where name = t.name) 'Age_In_Years'
from @TEMP t
```

Comment: Hello @Holmes IV- I am very new to programming. I tried searching on Duckduckgo to which I got few answers like select convert(varchar(10),DOB,103) from Customer; Now the reason I asked about multiple select statement is because I have 3 tables Customer, Transaction, prod_info. So my task is to Create a 360 view of different customer id . So one column required is age_in_months , other net sales which is a difference of two values, net quantity and like wise. Please suggest how to do it !

Comment: hello @Holmes IV - also SELECT Convert(INT, DATEDIFF(DAY, '12/12/1990',(select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103))*(12.0/365.0))) But my main motive is the column age_in_months should display the age in months. I run into lot of errors like character conversion.

Comment: Is it correct to write ?
Create View age_in_months
AS
Select Name, Customer_ID, DOB, (SELECT Convert(INT, DATEDIFF(DAY, '4-1-2008',GETDATE())*(12.0/365.0)) AS DOB_Months
),gender);
I know there are lot of errors but I want to know is it possible to write a query for a column while creating a view or a table ?

Comment: Do you want it in days or months ?  yy = year, mm = month, dd = days , did you want it as a decimal ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Yes, you can create a view with columns that come from multiple select statements.

As for the second question: The age in months can be calculated in a single expression. Usually, you calculate the difference of the dates in months, like you would when calculating the age (in years). Also, as with years, you will then have to check whether this number is too big and maybe subtract one. To say this in SQL:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, DOB, GETDATE()), DOB) > GETDATE()
    THEN DATEDIFF(month, DOB, GETDATE()) - 1
    ELSE DATEDIFF(month, DOB, GETDATE())
  END AS Age_In_Months
FROM YourTableWithDOB
```